# Why LEFT JOIN on LIKE statement gives different result on "_" changed to ","?

Tags: sqlite

`table1`:

| code | category |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ZMLND_XY_ABC |

`table2`:

| category | label |
| --- | --- |
| MLND | 3 |
| ZMLND | 4 |

I'd like to map `table1`'s `category` to `table2`'s `label` if the part of `table1`'s `category` separated by `_` equals `table2`'s `category`. For example, `ZMLND_XY_ABC` in `table1` matches `ZMLND` in `table2` while `ZMLND_XY_ABC` and `MLND` does not.

Query:

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on '_'||table1.category||'_' like '%_'||table2.category||'_%'
```

Result:

```
code  |    category     |  category_1  |  label
ABC   |  ZMLND_XY_ABC   |    MLND      |    3      <-  _MLND_ should not match
                                                       _ZMLND_XY_ABC_
ABC   |  ZMLND_XY_ABC   |    ZMLND     |    4
```

However, I replace `_` by `,`:

`table1`:

| code | category |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ZMLND,XY,ABC |

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on ','||table1.category||',' like '%,'||table2.category||',%'
```

Result:

| code | category | category_1 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ZMLND,XY,ABC | ZMLND | 4 |

Why are there different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of SQLITE `like` the `_` is as special a character as the `%`.
As you seem to know, the `%` matches multiple characteres.
What you seem to have missed is that the `_` matches any single character.
Compare e.g. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Have a look at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html concerning the `ESCAPE` optional syntax part, which probably can help you to write your query.